# does movie filter in ffmpeg 4.3.1 support png format picture

Tags: ffmpeg, lavfilters

I use ffmpeg's moive filter to add wartermark on my video.
The str is "const char *filter_descr = "movie=test.png:seek_point=3.2, scale=180:-1, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [over];[in] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [main];[main][over] overlay=16:16 [out]";"
it shows that can't find codec, but if the wartermark picture is bmp ,then it's ok.
I found that the png code exists in ffmpeg, it should support png decoder.

Comment: Why are you using the movie filter instead of adding `test.png` as a normal input? Example: `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i test.png -filter_complex "[1]scale=180:-1[img];[0][img]overlay=16:16" output.mp4`